# dimension of Weber set and selectope (as a operator)

Tags: game-theory, discrete-geometry, polytopes

Let $\Omega$ be a finite set of players. For a selector  $\alpha:(2^{\Omega}-\{\emptyset\})\rightarrow\Omega$, we define a marginal value operator as a linear operator $m^{\alpha}$
$$m^{\alpha}:\mathbb{R}^{2^{\Omega}-\{\emptyset\}}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{\Omega}:\;\left(m^{\alpha}(u_{S})\right)_{\alpha(S)}=1,\;\left(m^{\alpha}(u_{S})\right)_{i\neq\alpha(S)}=0$$ ($u_{S}$ is a unanimity basis, i.e. a cooperative game $u_{S}(T)=1$ iff $S\subseteq T
 $, $u_{S}(T)=0$ otherwise).
A special case is a selector defined by permutation $\pi$, $\pi(S)=max_{\pi}(S)$

It is known that $$ Conv\{m_{\pi}:\:\pi\:\textrm{is permutation}\}\subsetneqq Conv\{m_{\alpha}:\:\alpha\:\textrm{is selector}\}
 $$
except a small $\Omega$. But it is true that $$\dim(Conv\{m_{\pi}:\:\pi\:\textrm{is permutation}\})=\dim(Conv\{m_{\alpha}:\:\alpha\:\textrm{is selector}\})
 $$
?

Comment: Non-game reformulation: We have two sets of $0-1$ matrices  $ n\times2^{n}-1$, rows are indexed by elements of $\Omega$, columns by nonempty subsets:
$$A=\{M_{\pi}=(a_{iS}=1\Leftrightarrow i\:\textrm{is smallest element of }S\textrm{ wrt } \pi)_{n}^{2^{n}-1}\}$$
$$B=\{M_{\alpha}=(a_{\alpha(S),S}=1,a_{i\neq\alpha(S),S}=0)_{n}^{2^{n}-1},\alpha:(2^{\Omega}-\{\emptyset\})\rightarrow\Omega\:\textrm{s.t.}\:\forall_{S}\alpha(S)\in S\}$$
It is true that $dim(Conv(A))=dim(Conv(B))$ ?